# How to insert Prime symbol in Libreoffice Math

Tags: libreoffice

I'm sure that it's possible in a nicer way than just using an apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a variable x with 3 primes.

`nospace{x"'''"}`

[image]

Comment: this is OK, but what if I want a subscript properly located next to the 'x' as well?